# when do we use QMutexLocker relock and unlock?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

As the title suggests,how do you use QMutexLocker relock and unlock member function, I'm having in hard time figure out this how could be done.

1. Whether using RAII style of QMutexLocker always give promise fine locking state from data race?
2. If no, when such circumtances that likely occurs, so that we need to call unlock and relock function?
3. I see QMutexLocker  usage from this qt source https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/3b577dfe798bf5065a2bba4d7095709454aa709c:src/plugins/platforms/android/androidjnimenu.cpp
   It does implement different qmutex variable for use in QMutexLocker. And my question is when do we need  many ownership qmutex for use in different qmutexlocker like qt source above? and when do we need only single ownership qmutex for use in different qmutexlocker?

Could you give an example please for second question.. thanks

Comment: Can you rephrase question 1? It makes no sense.

Comment: ok corrected indentation

Comment: No, I meant the sentence.

Comment: You should look at the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmutexlocker.html). It will be very rare to use the `unlock` and `relock` functions.

Comment: @cmannett85, sorry Im not native english speaker and now should be correct :)

Comment: @o11c, really? this does make me sense how easy locking when QMutexLocker being used for getter and setter class, but Im not sure, if the things become more complex. Just asking anyone have experience on this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The typical use case for unlock and relock is get-modify-update:

```
class Foo {
  QMutex dataMutex;
  QVector<int> data;
public:
  /// Thread-safe
  void modify() {
    QMutexLocker lock(&dataMutex);
    QVector<int> copy = data;
    lock.unlock();

    copy << 42;

    lock.relock();
    data = copy;
  }
};
```